# How do i prevent recursion in my MongoDB database?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, morphia

I am making a simple social media platform and i am using MongoDB with Morphia and Spring boot.
In my database a user has a list of users that they follow, however if that list contains a user that also follows them, it creates an infite going back and foward of loading the data of each user. How can i prevent such an issue? i have tried enableing lazy loading with @Reference(lazy=true) but that does not help.

Comment: Don't include the actual user object, rather just a reference such as a name or ID of that user.

Comment: Lazy loading is generally the answer there.  It's possible you have that list of users in a `toString()`, e.g., that is forcing the resolution of those references.  Posting your entities would help.